# Can't restart windows processes when headless

Tags: .net, windows, process

All,

I have a windows headless machine (no monitor attached) running Win8.1 that hosts a .NET app that runs 24x7 and restarted nightly. The app runs a node.js process that has a problem that makes node exit abruptly.

While I try to work through the node problem (which isn't the topic of this post) I have added a bit of code to the app that restarts node when it aborts. Should be pretty simple, and the node process starts when the PC reboots but when node eventually aborts, the process 'Exited' event isn't raised until a console is connected to the machine, either by plugging in a monitor or thru a remote console like VNC then the restart code runs. If a console is attached it will always restart.

Any ideas how to make process start less dependent on having a console connected? I have tried a number of the process options but it doesn't make a difference.

Process start code (vb.net)

```
    Private Function LoadNodePlugins() As Boolean
        NodeProc.StartInfo.FileName = "node.exe"
        NodeProc.StartInfo.Arguments = "plugmgr.js"
        NodeProc.StartInfo.WorkingDirectory = "..\..\..\..\pluginMgr\pluginMgr"
        NodeProc.EnableRaisingEvents = True
        NodeProc.Start()
        Return True
    End Function
```

Process exit event handler

```
    Private Sub NodeProcess_HasExited(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles NodeProc.Exited
        If NodeProc.ExitCode > 0 Then                                    ' Don't capture normal termination
            WriteConsole(True, "WARNING: Node process has aborted (error code " + NodeProc.ExitCode.ToString() + "). Restarting")
            System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(5000)
            LoadNodePlugins()
        End If
    End Sub
```

Comment: If you comment out the call to `WriteConsole`, does that fix the problem?

Comment: No unfortunately. The process start spawns a command window that the Node writes to, as well as WriteConsole (wrapper for console.writeline) in the .NET parent app.

Comment: Do you know at what point the code is stalling?  I wouldn't have expected the presence of a monitor to make any difference, but it is known that Windows messaging doesn't work normally when the window station is locked.  When you plug in the monitor, do you also need to unlock the window station?  If the problem is not in node.js (i.e., the node process is exiting as expected when it fails) then you could probably bypass the issue by writing your code in C rather than in .NET, or by making it a system service rather than an interactive application.

Comment: I agree it's strange that the monitor makes a difference. I have added debug output but will have to wait until the Node problem reoccurs (it is intermittent) to see exactly where it is getting stuck. It's not easy to rewrite the .NET bits in C or as a system service as this should be a temporary workaround until I can solve the Node problem. It is very strange behaviour for .NET though.....